# Is there a text file in eclipse where one can see what plugins are installed?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I would like to get a list of plugins my eclipse installation has, is there a config file inside eclipse where I could get that info?

More or less I need the same info I get if I go to

```
Help -> About Eclipse Platform -> Installation Details -> Installed Software
```

If I get a single entry per plugin even better (in Installed Software there are usually several per plugin), but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is such file. Plugins folder is a mere repository for jar files. They may or may not be installed to your eclipse. Whether installed or not is described in a file called *profile*.

When you install new plugins, from wizard or dropins-folder, a new mutated copy of profile is created, and eclipse is activated with that new copy. If install fails eclipse reverts to the previous profile.

Try taking a look at
p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry

You can manage it with code (P2 Agent) or Director application ([P2 Director](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_director_application)).

You can get the active installed profile like this: (include a bunch of o.e.e.p2.* bundles first)

```
BundleContext context = Activator.getInstance().getContext();
IProvisioningAgentProvider provider = (IProvisioningAgentProvider) getService(context, IProvisioningAgentProvider.SERVICE_NAME);
IProvisioningAgent agent = provider.createAgent(agentLocation); // agentLocation = where profiles are
IProfileRegistry registry = (IProfileRegistry) agent.getService(IProfileRegistry.SERVICE_NAME);
String activeProfileId = (String) provisioningAgent.getService(IProvisioningAgent.INSTALLER_PROFILEID);
IProfile profile = registry.getProfile( activeProfileId );
```

And with profile you can query everything that is installed.

Answer (score 0):

it's not in one textfile, but inside the folder plugins there's a file for every plugin installed. The name of the each file contains the id and the version.

Comment: I already knew about that folder but it has less useful information than the 'Installed Software' view. Some plugins have a folder, others have files, and the number of files and folders is much larger. So not useful.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, under About Eclipse Platform → Installation Details → Configuration. Now, use Copy to Clipboard and save it to a text file.

This file contains a lot of information. Among other things, search for the string "`*** Plug-in Registry`". You will find all plugins listed there with the exact start (Active, Resolved, Active, etc).

Comment: thanks, but it is too verbose, there are tens of lines with internal eclipse plugins etc.

Comment: There's also a "features" section above the plugins version. You can copy the plugins section only, sort by name, and look at lines which are not org.eclipse. In any event, this is the plugins, this is what you asked for.

Answer (score -1):

in the end there is apparently no such info readily available, so in order to close the question I'll select this, taking a screenshot of the Help -> About Eclipse Platform -> Installation Details -> Installed Software dialog as best approximation